# How to overwrite Ruby DataMapper's create and first_or_create method?

Tags: ruby, overloading, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I could overwrite DataMapper's save, delete, destroy! method using module, such as:

```
require 'data_mapper'

module Record
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      include DataMapper::Resource
      property :id, DataMapper::Property::Serial
      alias :parent_save :save
      def save bar 
        # do additional thing with bar
      end
    end
  end
end

class User
  include Record
  property :name,String
end

DataMapper.finalize

# so i could call something like this:
x = User.new
x.name = 'something'
x.save 123
```

how to overwrite `create` and `first_or_create` method, when those methods are not found on `base.class_eval do`?

So i could call something like this:

```
User.first_or_create additional_param, name: 'something'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override class methods by adding this to your `class_eval` block:

```
class << self
  alias :parent_first_or_create, :first_or_create
  def first_or_create
    # ...
  end

  # do other things with class methods
end
```